# Make Smarty compile templates to memcache

Tags: php, smarty

I have a project that uses Smarty template engine (2.6). Point is I can't have it save files locally as it would mean saving to the repository. Same with cache.

My question is - how should I implement compiling templates to, for example, memcache?

I was playing with stream wrapper for it but maybe someone has a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every repository system has means of **excluding** files from tracking. Which you have to use, instead of reinventing a square wheel

Comment: I can't have it write files anywhere, how do I make smarty compile templates somewhere else? (that's why I tried memcache)

after your edit: I'll see what's my client's opinion on this, I just had to think of a way

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is necessary. Smarty templates are compiled to PHP files and on runtime these PHP files are included, just like native PHP scripts. You can think of caching PHP scripts with APC or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-compile the templates and ship them as a part of your application as read-only files. Thus it is not a decent solution it will work on such hosting environment.

If you are using Google App Engine with PHP you can use the cloud base storage as a stream with Smarty 3 to store all your files there.